# Giving input in sublime gdb on ST3?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using sublime text 3 with the plugin '***sublimeGdb***' and trying to give input to it via sublimegdb input box that appears below on pressing the "shift 
+ f5"  to a program whilst a debugging session .

```
int main(int argv, char **argc){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Lets say i was running the above program with sublimeGdb and put via breakpoint on the line `cout << a;`.

Now the gdb session waits for the input of **a** .When the try to give input by entering in the gdb input text box ,say I entered "**1**".it then appends some value to the front of the value entered and assign `int a = 121;`. Also I tried giving input arguments in the project settings with the line **"sublimegdb_arguments": "89"**. didn't work out .

1. How to properly give input values ?
2. How to see the **stdout** of the
   program?